# JSF add a commandLink tag or outputText tag depand on a boolean flag

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, javabeans

I have a `userBean` object with `name`, `id`, `boolean isConnected`.

I built a login page using JSF. If one login successfully, the next page is a table of all users (name, id)

What I want is on the column of the user who logged in his id will be shown in a `h:commandlink`, and the rest of the users id will be in an `h:outputText` tag.

When the user logged in his `isConnected` flag (`boolean`) is `true` and all other users are `false`.

Is there a way to insert a different tag depand on a certain flag like mine? Something like call a method on my `managerBean` that will send a different string depending on the user flag on the page `init`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use the `rendered` attribute of the `outputText` and `commandLink` tags.

For example, something like the following:

```xml
...
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.users}" var="user">
    ...
    <h:column>
        <h:commandLink rendered=#{user.connected} value="#{user.id}"/>
        <h:outputText rendered=#{!user.connected} value="#{user.id}"/>
    </h:column>
    ...
</h:dataTable>
...
```

Comment: Not a problem. More than happy to help.